# Будет ли утечка памяти, если выполнить этот код?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память

Все никак не могу понять будет-ли в данном коде утечка памяти или нет?
Собственно, я в методе pushBack() создаю новый массив большего размера что бы скопировать в него значения массива который передаю в функцию и добавить новое.
Далее я удаляю данные на которые указывает **arr**, и присваиваю ему адрес **midArr** который указывает на новый массив, после вывожу результат с помощью метода showArr() и снова удаляю данные на которые указывает *arr (но уже в main()). **Так вот как я понимаю после всей этой чистки памяти в роди должен остаться указатель midArr, или он удаляется из стека после завершения функции (так как эта переменная является локальной)?** Буду рад вашей помощи в этом вопросе.

```
void pushBack(int *&arr, int &size, const int value) {
    int *midArr = new int[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        midArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    midArr[size++] = value;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = midArr;
}
int main()
{
    int size = 10, value = 3, place=3;
    int *arr = new int[size];
    fillArr(arr, size);
    pushBack(arr, size, value);
    showArr(arr, size);
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Метод fillArr()

```
void fillArr(int *const arr, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
```

Метод showArr()

```
void showArr(const int *const arr, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы нет, если в `fillArr` все ok...

Comment: сам указатель midArr  прекращает свое существование после вызова функции, но  это не имеет значения, адрес же хранит нужный вам указатель `arr`.

Comment: Однозначно утечки нет.

Что до вашего вопроса, то здесь есть определенная терминологическая не то чтобы путаница, но...

Удаление указателя и удаление (`delete`, хотя на самом деле освобождение) памяти, на которую указывает указатель - это разные вещи. Переменная `midArr` локальная, память для нее выделена в стеке, по выходе из функции переменная будет удалена - т.е. выделенная для нее память может использоваться для других целей. Но это никак не связано с памятью, на которую она указывает. Эта память останется выделенной, помеченной в менеджере памяти как занятая и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

У вашей функции `int *midArr = new int[size + 1];` переменная `midArr` занимает в стеке 8 байт. На что указывать будут указатели не важно, так как указатель это элементарный тип без деструктора.